# Get the last count result of last query

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to use the output of this in an if and else statement how can i do this?

i've tried by directly putting the select query like this IF (select query) > 0 THEN, but it does not work. How can i achieve this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM service, kit, kit_has_part, part 
WHERE service.id = 1 and service.kitID = kit.id 
and kit.id = kit_has_part.kitID 
and kit_has_part.partID = part.id 
and part.stock > 0
```

Comment: use in mysql or php or what?

Comment: try to store the result of this query into another varibale. then pass this var. into the IF/ELSE cond.

Comment: mysql i'm creating a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to declare a variable and select the result into it. You can then use the variable in the IF. Something like the pseudocode'ish;

```
CREATE FUNCTION bop() RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE cnt INT;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt
  FROM service
  JOIN kit ON kit.id = service.kitid
  JOIN kit_has_part ON kit_has_part.kitid = kit.id
  JOIN part ON part.id =  kit_has_part.partid
  WHERE service.id = 1 AND part.stock > 0;

  IF cnt > 0 THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
//
```